# Deepin Software Centre unable to aunthenticate password

Tags: 11.10, kubuntu, software-center, password, authentication

I am using Kubuntu 11.10. I tried installing Deepin Software Centre in it. Installation was successful but when I launched the application it asked for password. Every time I entered the password, it showed me "wrong password" message.

Comment: Installed via deb package or source

Comment: via deb package

Comment: Now that you've installed the program, how are you running it, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Its asking for the root password which is disabled by default. To set the root password use `sudo passwd` and set it. Then enter it when Deepin prompts for it.

Comment: Normal password is enough

Comment: @user74558 This is [neither supported nor recommended](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) on Ubuntu. Instead, (1) a non-graphical program that prompts for a *root* password when run as a normal user can be [run as root with `sudo`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Usage), and (2) a graphical program that prompts for a *root* password when run as a normal user can be [run as root with `kdesudo`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo) (or `gksu`/`gksudo` if not using Kubuntu).